# Integer conversion database to json using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$list = array();
$sql="SELECT * FROM app_maths WHERE student_id=1043
UNION
SELECT * FROM comm_skills WHERE student_id=1043
UNION
SELECT * FROM eng_draw WHERE student_id=1043;";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$sub="subject";
$sem=intval('sem');

array_push($list,array("subject"=>$row[$sub],"sem"=>$row[$sem],"s1"=>$row['s1'],"s2"=>$row['s2']));

//  echo $sem;
}
echo json_encode(array('result' => $list ))."<hr>";
```

The database has **sem=1** in each row. And i can easily convert this information into json string but i want to convert into json as an `int` and not string for further calculations. Using `intval()` gives me the value **'sem'='1043'** that too in a string in JSON.

Comment: `$sem=intval('sem');` doesn't seem right to me. Try getting rid of that line, and using `intval($row['sem'])` in your push line.

Comment: Thnx bro i literally clapped.. change your comment into answer lemme vote up. Jon Stirling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sem=intval('sem');` doesn't seem right to me.

Try getting rid of that line, and using `intval($row['sem'])` in your push line, which will convert the actual array item value to an int.

Comment: i ve got low reputation but the vote up is recorded. Hopefully it might help u.. Anyways thnx alot.!

Comment: It's your question, so I'd expect you to be able to "accept" the answer after 15 mins. (I think it's 15 mins anyway :P)